# How to make all 'li' under any 'ul' equal width always using css when number of 'li' is dynamic, number of li may be 4, 5, 7 or 11

Tags: css

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7

I don't want to use different width separately for each condition

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: 'equal width' - could you describe a bit more what this means? Where would the required width be defined?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ul>
    <li class="flex items-center gap-2">
        <div class="number">{numberVariable}</div>
        <div class="text">{TextVariable}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

by default ul behavior, I think we can not achieve this but in this way we can achieve our results. I also tried to figure out the problem but by default ul, I was not able to achieve it.

```
`.flex{
    display: flex;
}
.items-center{
    align-items: center;
}`
```